# SQL Server temp table check performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-performance

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mytesttable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #mytesttable

SELECT id, name 
FROM 
INTO #mytesttable mytable
```

Question: is it good to check temp table existence (e.g: `OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mytesttable')` ) when I first time create this temp table inside a procedure?

What will be the best practice in terms of performance?

Comment: Yes....you have to check #temp table ...exists or not ....because..if you called the sp 2 time ...then first time it will excute proper and  2nd drop the table ...then it excute..

Comment: By the way...into Query is not proper...it should be like this SELECT id, name  INTO #mytesttable FROM mytable

Comment: It depends, is there any chance it could already exist? If there is then yes, if there isn't then no.

Comment: @Jack . . . Temporary tables are deleted at the end of the stored procedure, so this is unnecessary.  You can have even more assurance if you use a table variable instead of a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to check if table exists or not. and it doesn't have any performance impact. anyhow, temp tables automatically drops once procedure execution completes in sql server. sql server appends unique num with temp table name. so if same procedure executes more than once at same time also , it will not cause any issue. it depends on session. all procs executions have different session.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a good practice. I am always doing this at the beginning of the routine. In SQL Server 2016 + objects can DIE (Drop If Exists), so you can simplify the call:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #mytesttable;
```

Also, even at the end of the routine you temporary objects are destroyed and even the SQL Engine gives unique names to temporary tables, there is still another behavior to consider.

If you are naming your temporary table with same name, when nested procedure calls are involved (one stored procedure calls another) it is possible to get an error or corrupt your data. This is due to the fact that temporary table are visible in the current execution scope - so, #table in one procedure will be visible in the second called procedure (so you can modify its data or drop it).